# How to cast DTO object to Generic T type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i have this peace of code where i am returning a list of objects. but the return type is not allowing to return. 
this my interface class

```
interface SEC_Interface<T>
    {
        bool Add(T data);
        bool Update(T data);

        bool Delete(T data);

        List<T> GetAll();

        T GetById(int id);

        List<T> Search(string SearchTerm);
    }
```

Here is the method of class.My class is also generic type class and implementing this interface which is also generic.

```
public List<T> GetAll()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(conn, "SEC_GetAllUsers", null);

                    List<DTO_GetAll> result = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(dataRow => new DTO_GetAll
                        {
                          id = dataRow.Field<int>("id"),
                          FirstName = dataRow.Field<String>("FirstName"),
                            LastName = dataRow.Field<String>("LastName"),
                            Email = dataRow.Field<String>("Email"),
                            Address = dataRow.Field<String>("Address"),
                            Password = dataRow.Field<String>("Password"),
                            UserName = dataRow.Field<String>("UserName"),
                            Role_Id = dataRow.Field<int>("Role_Id"),
                            Status_Id = dataRow.Field<int>("Status_Id")
          }).ToList();

        return result;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you add the error message itself to the question and remove the image? I think that will be more helpful for people to answer your question.

Comment: Why do you want to use generics here ? You know your return type. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: because its just a simplest i can ask. i have more complex classes where i have applied the interface. which is applied to this as well. so if this one get resolved it will be helpfull for other as well

Comment: i have edit question please check it now

Answer (score 1):

Your implementing class can just declare the return type as `List<DTO_GetAll>`:

```
class SEC_DTO_GetAll : SEC_Interface<DTO_GetAll>
{
    public List<DTO_GetAll> GetAll()
    {

    }
}
```

You declare that `T` will be `DTO_GetAll` when you implement the interface.

Comment: public class SEC_User<T>: SEC_Interface<T>

Comment: again the class is generic which is implementing this interface

Comment: @Sikandar why make the implementing class generic, when the return type is specific? You will need an implementation class for each possible type `T`. Imagine you instantiated like `new SEC_User<DTO_GetAll>()`, how could the class know the specific behaviour required to get a list of `DTO_GetAll`?

Comment: that is what i am asking.

Comment: @Sikandar it can't; at some point you're going to need a specific implementation. Why do you want to keep the implementing class generic? Having a generic interface is fine, as you can have an implementation for each DTO, but each implementation needs to be concrete.